# Why can Python's "request" do this, but not JS fetch?

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests

I found a website that you can send .scss code to, and it returns the converted .css code back
So I wanted to try and see if I can make a JS program that takes scss code in the HTML document and sends it to that website, and then gets the data that it returns and replaces the scss code with css code, and then loads the website.

My Python script looks like this:

```py
import requests
response = requests.post(
    url='https://jsonformatter.org/service/scssTocss',
    data={'css':"$a:red;a{color:$a;}"}
)
print(response.text)
```

This prints out this (as it should):

```
a {
  color: red; 
}
```

But then when I try to convert that python code into something that runs on JS, it no longer works, and I run into a bunch of CORS issues.

Im looking for a function in JS that can basicly do this:

```js
function sccs_2_css(scss_input){
    // Magic words here...

    return scss;
}

console.log( sccs_2_css("$a:red;a{color:$a;}") );
```

And the output should then be:

```
a {
  color: red; 
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: @GabrielLupu A string with the value of "$a:red;a{color:$a;}". Basicly, just scss code in a string

Comment: Well, so, the site blocks CORS. Period. End of story. CORS affects in-browser use, but not Python requests. Have you tried reading something about CORS? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 3):

You can use [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere).

```js
const data = new FormData();
data.append("css", "$a:red;a{color:$a;}");
fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://jsonformatter.org/service/scssTocss', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
  }).then(res => res.text()).then(text => console.log(text));
```

Comment: This seems to work fine, but im still confused over why Python can do the request without issues?

Comment: Because CORS only affects in browser requests.